# I m getting 4 times values of same data in tableview cell, so kindly help to pass the data with one value

Tags: ios

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, pass {
    
    var array = [String]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPush: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as!TableViewCell
        cell.lblName.text = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblFullName.text = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblRollno.text = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblClass.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnPush(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as!SecondVC
        vc.mac = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func Datapass(Name: String, FullName Address: String, Rollno: String, Class: String) {
        self.array.append(Name)
        self.array.append(Address)
        self.array.append(Rollno)
        self.array.append(Class)
        tblView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

protocol pass {
    func Datapass(Name:String, FullName:String, Rollno:String, Class:String)
}

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textFldName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldFullName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldRollno: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldClass: UITextField!
    var mac:pass?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnAdd(sender: UIButton) {
       mac?.Datapass(Name: textFldName.text!, FullName: txtFldFullName.text!, Rollno: txtFldRollno.text!, Class: txtFldClass.text!)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are appending four values to your array.  You probably want to create a `struct` to store your data and append an instance of that struct

Answer (score 0):

your adding data to your array the wrong way. your adding 4 parameter
and your array will be like this:

array: 0:name|1:Address|2:Rollno|3:Class

and when your reading this from table every time you map this:

```
 cell.lblName.text = array[0]
 cell.lblFullName.text = array[0]
 cell.lblRollno.text = array[0]
 cell.lblClass.text = array[0]
```

every time table only reads one element of array for 4 times! you are not changing indexpath.row , it will change it's number after loading 1 cell.

- the right way to do this is code below:

  ```
  struct DbModel{
     var name:String
     var address:String
     var rollno:String
     var `class`:String
  }
  ```

  var array :[DbModel] = []

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
  let model = array[indexPath.row]
  cell.lblName.text     = model.name
  cell.lblFullName.text = model.address
  cell.lblRollno.text   = model.rollno
  cell.lblClass.text    = model.class
  return cell
  }

  ```
        func Datapass(Name: String, FullName Address: String, Rollno: String, Class: String) {
           let model =  DbModel(name: Name, address: Address, rollno: Rollno, class: Class)
            self.array.append(model)
            tblView.reloadData()
            }
  ```